# MySQL 5.7 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM vBOX electricity/shutdown immediately problems

Tags: server, permissions, virtualbox, apache2, mysql

I have a VM Virtual Box with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as server mode. Where I live there is a lot of electricity problems, and then my machine and therefore the VM shuts down unexpectedly. And other scenarios, is for memory problem (I guess) the Windows blue screen comes into action and therefore I have to reboot all my machines.

When trying to reconnect to my VM, it's broken. There are a lot of mysql problems comes into action, sometimes comes this:

```
MYUSER@MYMACHINE:/etc/mysql$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

And then I look at `/var/log/mysql/ERROR.LOG` and found this using `tail -1`

```
[ERROR] Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged or in unsupported 3.20 format.
```

BUT MOST OF THE TIME THE ONLY MESSAGE IT COMES OUT IS THIS:

```
MYUSER@MYMACHINE:/etc/mysql$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Anyone knows how to avoiding to do so. It crashes when the DB size is more than 100MB. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Just a comment. I bought my 550 Watt UPS on sale and it was only 60 bucks or something like that....

Answer (score 0):

Run a check/repair on your data files
*assuming that your MySQL runs MyISAM tables as the default setup*
*systemctl and myisamchk must be run as root*

```
systemctl stop mysql
myisamchk /var/lib/*/*.MYI
```

Note: if you get error 140, its a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87729). There is a workaround:

```
find /var/lib/*/*.MYI | sed -e 's/\(\.MYI\)*$//g' | xargs myisamchk
```

Then restart the service and try again

```
systemctl mysql
mysql -u root -p -h localhost
```

Comment: IIRC We used to do ISAM file checks in the old DOS days as part of Day End Processing. Shouldn't people have this option in a menu or is it the database is never brought down in modern times?

Comment: In modern times, there is no end of day. We schedule check & optimize tasks on online databases with `mysqlcheck`